# Two animations at the same time without setstate

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

So I am struggling with annoying problem. I want to run 2 animations at the same time and somewhat it does not work without:

```
animationController.addListener(() {
  setState(() {});
});
```

Which is making everything choppy, which I would like to eradicate.

When I delete `setState` in both of my animation controllers and run this function:

```
 void animateButton() {
    if (_forward) {
      animationController.reverse();
      animationController2.reverse();
      _forward = false;
    } else {
      animationController.forward();
      animationController2.forward();
      _forward = true;
    }
  }
```

It runs just the first animation controller, without second one. Animations are simple tweens which are opposite to each other, so I was thinking about doing something which would use one tween and for second property I would do some inverse function, but I can't think of any solution for this, so it would actually work. Maybe I am missing something simple.

Here is my full code:

```
class _DetailScreenState extends State<DetailScreenWidget>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  final GlobalKey<SendWidgetState> _key = GlobalKey();

  AnimationController animationController;
  Animation<double> tween;
  AnimationController animationController2;
  Animation<double> tween2;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
    animationController = AnimationController(
        vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 800));
    tween = Tween<double>(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(
        CurvedAnimation(parent: animationController, curve: Curves.easeOut));
    animationController.addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    });

    animationController2 = AnimationController(
        vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 800));
    tween2 = Tween<double>(begin: 1.0, end: 0.0).animate(
        CurvedAnimation(parent: animationController2, curve: Curves.easeOut));
    animationController2.addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    });
  }
  void showHideSendView() {
    if (_forward) {
      animationController.reverse();
      animationController2.reverse();
      _forward = false;
    } else {
      animationController.forward();
      animationController2.forward();
      _key.currentState.initView();
      _forward = true;
    }
  }

  void showTransactions() {
    setState(() {
      showHideSendView();
    });
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(children: [
      
      SafeArea(
        child: Stack(children: [
          TransactionWidget(
            opacity: tween2,
            getTransactions: _getTransactions,
          ),
          SizeTransition(
            sizeFactor: tween,
            axis: Axis.vertical,
            axisAlignment: -1,
            child: SendWidget(
              key:_key,
              func: shrinkSendView,
              height: tween,
            ),
          ),
          BalanceCard(
              getBalanceFuture: _getBalanceFuture,
              onPressSend: showTransactions),
        ]),
      ),
    ]);
  }
}
```

I learned about `staggered animation` in flutter, however I need **2 animations to run at the same time without `setState`**. And for that I didn't find on the internet anything, so I resort to asking questions here.

Comment: why do you need `setState`? Get rid of it. of all `animationController2.addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    });` code

Comment: `parent: animationController2` this is where you bind your controller to animation, it manages state changes.

Comment: Sorry, I don't funny understand what you mean. If I get rid of those `setState`, only one animation works for some reason? Not sure what you mean with `parent: animationController2`, when I have there as a parent for the `tween2` @Simon Sot

Comment: Use same controller for both animations. If you need both animations play in same time, just delete `animationController2` and use only `animationController`.

Comment: Oh it's possible, I will try it. Thanks!

Comment: Well I tried that and it only does the first tween and for the second one, it just makes that one widget invisible without animation. @Simon Sot Is there any other problem with which I am missing....

Comment: And it works with one controller when I add there `animationController.addListener(() {       setState(() {});     });` I mean I don't understand why it would need that.... Because without it only one tween is animated.

Comment: I will write an example for you in a few minutes.

Comment: No need, I solved it. `FadeTransition` is what I was looking for. @SimonSot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright I solved it, I guess there is a need for `statefulWidget` which updates on every step of the animation or maybe I am imagine things, now the working code, without stuttering.

I used advice by @Simon Pot and on the top of that I wrapped widget into `FadeTransition`

Here is the code:

```
class _DetailScreenState extends State<DetailScreenWidget>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  final GlobalKey<SendWidgetState> _key = GlobalKey();

  AnimationController animationController;
  Animation<double> tween;
  Animation<double> tween2;

  Future _getBalanceFuture;
  Future _getTransactions;

  bool _forward = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    animationController = AnimationController(
        vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 800));
    tween2 = Tween<double>(begin: 1.0, end: 0.0).animate(
        CurvedAnimation(parent: animationController, curve: Curves.easeOut));
    tween = Tween<double>(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(
        CurvedAnimation(parent: animationController, curve: Curves.easeOut));

    _getBalanceFuture = getBalance();
    _getTransactions = _getTranData();
  }

 
  void animateButton() {
    if (_forward) {
      animationController.reverse();
      _forward = false;
    } else {
      animationController.forward();
      _key.currentState.initView();
      _forward = true;
    }
  }

  void showTransactions() {
      animateButton();
  }


  @override
  void dispose() {
    animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(children: [
      SafeArea(
        child: Stack(children: [
          FadeTransition(
            opacity: tween2,
            child: TransactionWidget(
            getTransactions: _getTransactions,
          ),
            ),
          SizeTransition(
            sizeFactor: tween,
            axis: Axis.vertical,
            axisAlignment: -1,
            child: SendWidget(
              key:_key,
              func: shrinkSendView,
              height: tween,
            ),
          ),
          BalanceCard(
              getBalanceFuture: _getBalanceFuture,
              onPressSend: showTransactions),
        ]),
      ),
    ]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Read the first part of this article, it will solve your query along with the reason why you should not use setState for custom animations.

https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-laggy-animations-how-not-to-setstate-f2dd9873b8fc

What you basically do here is instead of using setState and rebuilding the whole widget everytime you call it, you remove the listener and the setState inside it.

Then you wrap your to be animated widgets inside an AnimatedBuilder and pass your animation controller as a parameter in it. Now if you will look closely it has builder and child parameters too.

Place the part of your widget will not be changed throughout the animation inside the child widget. (For eg: If you are trying to animate the position of a container, then you can place the whole container widget inside the child parameter as the contents inside it won't be getting updated during the animation.

Instead of animating the whole widget, this will not rebuild the child widget everytime your update the animating frame leading to a smoother animation.

The rest of the widget will be affected by the change in animation controller's value should be placed inside the builder function which takes the provides the new value of animation controller and the child widget you just initialized.

Refer the article for implementation of AnimatedBuilder widget.